# How do I strip out the contents of my Pagedown editor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wmd-editor

I'm not even sure if this is possible, I am using the excellent Pagedown editor (used on  this site). Usually my text is in an textarea...

```
<textarea name="Description">

</textarea>
```

And my controller class picks this up without a problem.  But because I'm using PageDown I have to use a div...

```
<div class="wmd-preview" id="wmd-preview" name="Description">

</div>
```

How do I get my controller to map the InnerText of this Html block to my description? And I wants to keep the markup too obviously :-)

Comment: You would like to post the content of this div on the form submit, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, and you're using jQuery could you do this?

```
$('textarea[name="Description"]').html($('#wmd-preview').html());
```

Comment: When do I do it though? Can I raise an event that will bind the html to that textarea before the page submits? Its messy but if there isnt another solution I can. Just not sure how to make sure the script fires before http POST!?

Comment: How are you doing your POST? Can you modify your page/form to use `jQuery.ajax(options)`? One of the properties of the `options` argument is named `data` where you could add the parameter name your controller is expecting and give it the value I described above.